# PDOのエラー文を表示させるには

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

プログラミング初心者です。
phpからPDOでDBを操作したいのですが、構文エラーがあると「localhost ページは機能していません」と表示されてしまいます。
これだと何処にエラーがあるのか分かりません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

というのをtry catchのtryに入れてみましたが、これは関係ありませんか？

php.iniでの恒久的な設定（[参考](http://qiita.com/mpyw/items/2f9955db1c02eeef43ea#%E5%85%A8%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%82%92%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA)）

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
display_errors = On
```

も関係ありませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

はじめに `php -l file.php` のように対象のファイルのシンタックスチェックをかけてみてください。(画像のようなエラーが出る場合、最初に疑はれるのはPHPのsyntax errorです)

また、`$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`は`try-catch`の中でも外でも特に問題ありません。